# Using Functions with Returns and If / Else Statements

Tags: javascript, function, return

Sorry if that title was unclear, let me explain.

I'm teaching myself JavaScript using Codecademy.com

I'm at a point where I'm learning functions using if / else statements and using returns to produce a result instead of console.log like I'm used to.

Anyways, the code I'm writing at this point in my training is...

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) 
{
    if (sleepCheck >= 8);
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much";
}; 
else 
{
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The code returns a red error message saying

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'"

So I know it's, obviously, at the "else" part but I'm not sure how.

I came across this website so I need some help. If you can it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/WB75G/)

**Change your JavaScript to the following:**

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8)  {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much";
    }
    else {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

**Description:**

There were multiple issues with syntax, using a `;` when not at the end of a line of code but rather the end of an if declaration.  Also there was some issue with the `if` and `else` logic.  Also inside the function you should be using `numHours` as that's the parameter of the function while `sleepCheck` is the function itself and won't make sense to use.

***Note:** I used console.log on the 3 function call to make debugging easier.  Feel free to call the function any way you want.*

**Detailed Errors**

```
//This line is perfect
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) 
{
    //This line shouldn't end in a ; as it is invalid syntax you are opening an if also should use the function parameter of numHours not sleepCheck
    if (sleepCheck >= 8);
    //this line isn't reached because of the above error there isn't an error here
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much";
//This also doesn't need to have a ; and shouldn't be closing the } as you are ending the function here
}; 
//This is now ignored because of the above but is good, doesn't line up with the above if because of the }; which should just be a }
else 
{
    //All good
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Comment: Remind me never to bother responding to questions while using an ipad :)

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colon at the end of the `if` statement is declaring that the statement is done. Get rid of it (the one on line 5) and it should work.

Comment: Still does not work unfortunately. Now it says, "Expected an identifier, instead saw else."

Answer (score 0):

I used 'else if' because in the instructions it said 
**Otherwise (else) if the number of hours of sleep is less than 8, have the computer return "Get some more shut eye!";**  So I assumed I needed to.  It worked though.  *shrugs*

```
    var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8)  {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else if (numHours < 8) {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};

console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Comment: else in this situation does the same thing unless numHours is not a number and thereby isn't able to `greater than equal` or `less than` so it wouldn't do anything in those situations

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the semicolon after the if statement: if (sleepCheck >= 8); <---

Here's a useful rule to keep in mind:

In JavaScript never place a semicolon just before an opening curly brace or an opening parentheses because it will make the parser jump over the code block that follows.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. Here is one that really works:\

```html
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
if(numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    } else 
{
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

On lines 3 and 5, delete the semicolon. They are causing your else syntax error. Make sure you include a semicolon on line 9 to end the function as per the instructions in the Code Academy lesson.